# Search word with regular expression PHP

Tags: php

I have string `/ro/weather-kyiv-4944/`.Need get `ro` in this string.

I used `preg_match` php

```
preg_match('\/(ro)\/', $url, $matches);
```

result null. Help me pls guys.

Upd: need `ro` write in variable

Comment: The delimeter from your regex patter are invalid : ``` Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash```

You should use ```preg_match('#\/(ro)\/#', $url, $matches);```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing your delimiter characters.

Using `#` or `$` as delimiters is useful because you won't have to escape your `/` slashes.

Try the following:

```
preg_match('#/(?<language>.*?)/#', '/ro/weather-kyiv-4944/', $matches);

print_r($matches);
```